# memory usage goes over physical limitation in iOS (using ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have 2 view controllers, A and B. I am currently on A and i have a button which takes me to B. Now, i am testing this app for memory usage, and i found that going back and forth from A -> B takes up huge memory. I have attached .trace file also. It's over 1GB, which is physical RAM limit. I know that there is virtual memory concept to handle this situation. But, i am wondering why iOS has not killed my app?

Please help me understand this.

(Warning: I have zipped the file and reduced it to 226 MB, original file was 1.06 GB)

Link to Instruments4.trace file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4dFBFVTNrSVV3eFU/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)presentSearchScene
{
    if ([[[[self.navigationController viewControllers][0] class] description] isEqualToString:@"SearchVC"])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navSearch"] animated:NO completion:^{

        }];
    }
}
```

I think that issue is that i present view controller without creating it's property first. I will do it and update the question here.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on the downvote please?

Comment: You didn't ask a coding question - you asked for open ended help. That said you should log in your initial (or viewdidload) and dealloc to verify that as you go back and forth you are either create/deleting controllers or only doing the create once. Also that you are not re-creating other objects.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will keep this in mind. Dealloc is not being called. And i am not creating anything that i own. So, should i delete this question or keep it?

Comment: Well, you can either completely re-write it or write another that is a specific code related question. Look, I didn't down vote you and you obviously are not a noobie with 2K points. But you must know the drill - there are many people here who take a very narrow view of the rules. The memory trace is of no use by itself - you should be able to track this down by looking in obvious places. You may find this of some interest: https://github.com/dhoerl/ObjectTracker - but really your issue is almost for sure some misunderstanding. If you keep creating new view controllers but never releasing...

Comment: @DavidH, thanks for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate it. I might have caught the issue here (by your suggestion on never deallocating that object - why didn't i think of that before!!!!). My colleague has presented a view controller directly, also i think it's the only issue. I have edited the code. And i think presenting view controller without creating the object is the issue.

Comment: "going back and forth from A -> B takes up huge memory" Back and forth? This suggests that `navSearch` is never being _dismissed_. Typically this happens because someone has set up a circular segue path in the storyboard: instead of unwinding / dismissing from B, B presents A - so that A presents B which presents A which presents B which presents A... and so on, piling up multiple copies of the same view controllers over and over. You can easily detect this situation with some logging.